# How to dynamically access to object properties?

Tags: typescript

I need to dynamically access to object property in forEach. But I get an error: "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'"

I have tried to use props[key] or props.key, but I receive the same error

```
Object.keys(props).forEach(key => element.setAttribute(key, props[key]));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to create a specific string-keyed type for your object, you'll need to create a general one for Javascript objects:

```
interface IPojo {
  [key: string]: any,
}

const div = document.createElement('div');

const obj: IPojo = {
  'data-src': 'some-url',
  'data-width': 2,
};

Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => div.setAttribute(key, obj[key]));
```

By declaring it an implementation of that string-keyed general interface, the typechecker will correctly infer that your dynamic access is ok.

If your object is homogenous in terms of values you can make this even more type-safe by using a generic:

```
interface IHomogenousObject<T> {
  [key: string]: T,
}

const obj2: IHomogenousObject<string> = {
  'data-src': 'some-url',
};
```

And now the compiler will preserve the type safety of the string value pulled from the object.

Here's the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=20&ssc=3&pln=14&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAUD2ArTyDeAUMsgNoDWEAngFzIDOYUoA5gLp1whUA0hAvoUIJMIRsgAmwAG7IAvJMwIArgFsI4AHQIoEOJACiAGwjrwACgDkU6ZYCUAbiEixYZJgBG2Ohhx4FRCTW+nAAtPRQCJZ0lvSY6qHKUEaWfEESIaEA7sASYAAW0cgATHz8ToQA8l4QCGCalFT05p7YdpowmFAGiPnmjfIAfJIymvQQYACCYEzAHsqQ-dQ87l4U1Gx2jkKgkLCIKKgAEvGYLBqYyvTV2LVgADwAKsOBZI10jMwg7HSPZc6icStYo+E6qM4XK43O73T6sYYBYjIYJgMIRKIxOIJJIpMpOIA).

Comment: Thanks, that is really helped me

Comment: @DenCПрограммирование if you found it useful please accept my answer (little green checkmark). Glad to help!

Comment: This is super helpful! I was struggling with this as well.